# How to loop through multiple string variables in a for-loop?

Tags: python-3.x, string, for-loop

I have multiple string variables that store some text data. I want to perform the same set of tasks on all strings. How can I achieve this in Python?

```
string_1 = "this is string 1"
string_2 = "this is string 2"
string_3 = "this is string 3"

for words in string_1:
    return the second word
```

Above is just an example. I want to extract the second word in every string. Can I do something like:

```
for words in [string_1, string_2, string_3]:
    return the second word in each string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do

```py
for sentence in [string_1, string_2, string_3]:
   print(sentence.split(' ')[1]) # Get second word and do something with it
```

This will work assuming that you have minimum of two words in the string and each separated by a space.

Comment: The return statement exits after the first iteration. This doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah it is. Sorry for that. Made the change now

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension to chain up the second word in those strings. `split()` breaks your sentence down into word components by consuming spaces.

```
lines = [string1, string2, string3]

>>>lines[0].split()
['this', 'is', 'string', '1']

>>>[line.split()[1] if len(line.split()) > 1 else None for line in lines]
['is', 'is', 'is']
```

**Edit** Added conditional checks to prevent indexing failures

Comment: better use `line.split()` so if there are multiple spaces it still works. Also, the issue with listcomp is that if the sentence has only 1 word, it crashes when accessing the second element.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Switched to using `split` without the character argument per your suggestion and added a conditional statement to prevent indexing errors. Thanks for pointing out!